# Shared Internet On LAN

Tags: windows, windows-xp, internet, lan

I am on LAN and internet connection is slow because of multiple users. My connection is also coming from someone else.

Can I control/get more speed than others?
Is any software out there to do this?

Comment: How are you sharing the connection?  Are you all on a network with a common connection, or are you using connection sharing to another PC in the network?

Comment: @JNK: It is common connection through LAN coming from one single PC to other four computers.

Comment: See also this similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/339716/how-to-equally-share-speed-of-a-dsl-modem/1210161

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your router supports Quality of Service (QoS), you can set QoS priority based on application, protocol, port, IP or Mac address, etc.

You say you are getting your internet from someone else. So basically you do not have control over router settings correct?

Comment: Yes I do not have control over it, anything I can still do to get around?

Comment: If it is a router that you have no access or control over, you are at the mercy of the network admin.  You can TRY to access the router firmware, if they haven't changed from the default PW you could potentially get in.