# How to equally share speed of a dsl modem?

Tags: internet, speed, lan, dsl-modem, adsl2+

I have a `DSL` modem and I want to **equally** share the speed among the users because else if someone of them uses `IDM`(`Internet Download Manager`) the speed of all the other users sometimes decreases to such an extent that even the websites do not open. 
Is there anything I can do to equally share the speed among the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a old computer lying around you could install pfsense on that computer and apply limits for each system.

Comment: The procedure is detailed here https://superuser.com/a/1210164/257859