# More browsing speed on Shared Internet via Hub

Tags: browsing, hub

We have a BSNL broadband internet connection. Two users are sharing the connection **via a hub** directly (**no connection between 2 computers**). One user doesn't need more browsing speed. But the other user does need more speed as he watches videos, does videos chats and plays online games.

Is there any way to control the access speeds in both computers?(One is laptop & another one is desktop. And desktop needs more speed here.)

Note: I checked [this question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/168273/shared-internet-on-lan) but I couldn't get the solution.

Comment: Router model and computers OS would be good to know, the more information the merrier! :)

Comment: Laptop has Windows XP, desktop has Ubuntu 12.04. And ADSL router.

Comment: Are you saying that the occasional/light traffic from the user that doesn't need more speed sometimes causes problems for the user that does need more speed?

Comment: Simply put, a person always has to get more speed compared with the other person.

Comment: @Bruno Pereira: Using **beetel 110TC1 ADSL2+ROUTER**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good way. The bandwidth you're trying to preserve is the inbound bandwidth from your ISP to you. By the time your hub receives a packet, the earliest it could do anything, that packet has already consumed your inbound bandwidth. Unfortunately, residential Internet access is just not designed to do this.

There are ways you can preserve latency during bulk downloads so you can game while you're watching videos. But that's about it. (The basic idea is that you limit the device doing the bulk downloads to about 85% of your bandwidth. That doesn't slow it down very much, but it does keep the queues much emptier, improving latency. You configure this in the computer itself.)